# Error no deseado en PANDAPOWER OPF AC al intentar combinar fuera de servicio controlable y no controlable en servicio

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

¿Alguien sabe cómo solucionar el error que se genera en el OPF AC de pandapower al intentar combinar generadores controlables fuera de servicio y generadores no controlables en servicio?

Ejemplo mínimo:

```py
import pandapower as pp
net = pp.create_empty_network()
bus = pp.create_bus(net, vn_kv=110., name="Bus 2")
pp.create_ext_grid(net, bus=bus, vm_pu=1.00, name="Grid Connection")
pp.create_gen(net, bus=bus, p_mw=5, min_p_mw = 5, max_p_mw = 20, name='gen 1')
pp.create_gen(net, bus=bus, p_mw=5, min_p_mw = 5, max_p_mw = 20, name='gen 3')

net.gen[['in_service', 'controllable']] = [[False, True],
                                           [True, False]]

pp.runopp(net,verbose = True)
```

Output:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-47fe18b0aa9e> in <module>
      9                                            [True, False]]
     10 
---> 11 pp.runopp(net,verbose = True)

C:\Users\Daniel Rueda\.conda\envs\Tesis\lib\site-packages\pandapower\run.py in runopp(net, verbose, calculate_voltage_angles, check_connectivity, suppress_warnings, switch_rx_ratio, delta, init, numba, trafo3w_losses, consider_line_temperature, **kwargs)
    355     _check_bus_index_and_print_warning_if_high(net)
    356     _check_gen_index_and_print_warning_if_high(net)
--> 357     _optimal_powerflow(net, verbose, suppress_warnings, **kwargs)
    358 
    359 

C:\Users\Daniel Rueda\.conda\envs\Tesis\lib\site-packages\pandapower\optimal_powerflow.py in _optimal_powerflow(net, verbose, suppress_warnings, **kwargs)
     39     init_results(net, "opf")
     40 
---> 41     ppc, ppci = _pd2ppc(net)
     42 
     43     if not ac:

C:\Users\Daniel Rueda\.conda\envs\Tesis\lib\site-packages\pandapower\pd2ppc.py in _pd2ppc(net, sequence)
    113         aux._set_isolated_buses_out_of_service(net, ppc)
    114 
--> 115     _build_gen_ppc(net, ppc)
    116 
    117     if "pf" in mode:

C:\Users\Daniel Rueda\.conda\envs\Tesis\lib\site-packages\pandapower\build_gen.py in _build_gen_ppc(net, ppc)
     51     _init_ppc_gen(net, ppc, f)
     52     for element, (f, t) in gen_order.items():
---> 53         add_element_to_gen(net, ppc, element, f, t)
     54     net._gen_order = gen_order
     55 

C:\Users\Daniel Rueda\.conda\envs\Tesis\lib\site-packages\pandapower\build_gen.py in add_element_to_gen(net, ppc, element, f, t)
     80         _build_pp_ext_grid(net, ppc, f, t)
     81     elif element == "gen":
---> 82         _build_pp_gen(net, ppc, f, t)
     83     elif element == "sgen_controllable":
     84         _build_pp_pq_element(net, ppc, "sgen", f, t)

C:\Users\Daniel Rueda\.conda\envs\Tesis\lib\site-packages\pandapower\build_gen.py in _build_pp_gen(net, ppc, f, t)
    220         ppc = _check_gen_vm_limits(net, ppc, gen_buses, gen_is)
    221         if "controllable" in net.gen.columns:
--> 222             ppc = _enforce_controllable_vm_pu_p_mw(net, ppc, gen_is, f, t)
    223 
    224 

C:\Users\Daniel Rueda\.conda\envs\Tesis\lib\site-packages\pandapower\build_gen.py in _enforce_controllable_vm_pu_p_mw(net, ppc, gen_is, f, t)
    184     # if there are some non controllable gens -> set vm_pu and p_mw fixed
    185     if np.any(not_controllable):
--> 186         bus = net["gen"]["bus"].values[not_controllable]
    187         vm_pu = net["gen"]["vm_pu"].values[not_controllable]
    188         p_mw = net["gen"]["p_mw"].values[not_controllable]

IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 2 but corresponding boolean dimension is 1
```

Estaba analizando el error y pude identificar:

- Primero se crea una <class 'numpy.ndarray'> booleana con el estado de encendido o apagado de los generadores.

`[False, True]`

- Luego se crea una <class 'numpy.ndarray'> booleana con la característica de los generadores si son controlables, dependiendo del arreglo previamente creado (solo los generadores en servicio).

`[False]`

- Ahora a este arreglo se invierte la lógica booleana de cada elemento para obtener un arreglo con la característica de los generadores si no son controlables, en base al arreglo creado previamente (solo los generadores en servicio)

`[True]`

- Finalmente se crea una <class 'numpy.ndarray'> con los índices de los buses a los que están conectados los generadores controlables, pero aquí es donde se genera el error ya que la dimensión de la serie pandas de la que el array incluye generadores fuera de servicio while array para filtrar la característica controlable ya considerados solo generadores en servicio.

Se debería obtener un array: `[1]`, pues es el índice del generador no controlable